# I have two if statements inside one for loop, why does it sometimes run the second if statement before the first statement?

Tags: javascript

I have this block of code and sometimes the first if statement is ran first and other times the second if statement is ran first. I'm not sure why this is the case since I thought javascript was synchronous.

```
for (let i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++) { 
      if (dataObject[i].TEAM_NAME === team1) {
          console.log('1');
      }

      if (dataObject[i].TEAM_NAME === team2) {
          console.log('2');
      }
  }
```

the actual results logs 2 before 1. I need 1 to be logged before 2.

When I log the dataObjects coming in, it seems like the if statements are being ran based off of alphabetical order but I'm not sure how that's possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would add a `console.log()` *outside* either `if` statement at the top of the loop so that you can tell when an iteration happens.

Comment: That's simply because the second condition is truthy first, it has nothing to do with the loop increment.

Comment: I think you can simply use if(){} else if(){} instead the two if(){} to achieve 1 first before 2

Answer (score 4):

This would only happen if `team2` appeared in `dataObject` before `team1`. If you don't want that to happen, you're going to have to reorder `dataObject` to prevent it, or save the result for `team2` until after the loop finishes, or perform two passes, one solely for `team1`, one solely for `team2`. There's other approaches that get more and more weird, but fundamentally, the problem is you asked it to iterate `dataObject` in order and report values as soon as they're seen, and your values don't always appear in the order you expect.